# Update table value based on presence in multiple possible arrays (SQL)

Tags: sql

I have a members table with regions values in it. This table is first populated at sign up.

The states are sorted into an array for each region:

```
$region[1] = array("FL","GA","NC","SC","USVI","PR");
$region[2] = array("DC","KY","MD","OH","VA","WV");
$region[3] = array("DE","NJ","NY","PA");
$region[4] = array("CT","MA","ME","NH","RI","VT");
$region[5] = array("IA","IL","IN","MO","MI");
$region[6] = array("AL","AR","LA","MS","TN");
$region[7] = array("AZ","NM","OK","TX");
$region[8] = array("CO","KS","MN","MT","NE","ND","SD","UT","WI","WY");
```

I then do a recursive search to populate the table based on the region for that state.

```
$member_region = (recur_search($_SESSION['session_table_membersignup_mailing_state'], $region)) ? recur_search($_SESSION['session_table_membersignup_mailing_state'], $region) : 9;
```

I added additional regions, so that when new users sign up it will sort them based on the new arrays:

```
$region[1] = array("FL","GA","NC","SC","USVI","PR");
$region[2] = array("DC","KY","MD","OH","VA","WV");
$region[3] = array("DE","NJ","NY","PA");
$region[4] = array("CT","MA","ME","NH","RI","VT");
$region[5] = array("IA","IL","IN","MO","MI");
$region[6] = array("AL","AR","LA","MS","TN");
$region[7] = array("AZ","NM","OK","TX");
$region[8] = array("ND","NE","MI","MN","SD","WI");
$region[9] = array("AK","CA","NV","OR","WA","HI");
$region[10] = array("CO","ID","MT","UT","WY");
```

I'm running into issues on how to retroactively update the sql table for existing members using the new arrays.

Bsically: I need to loop through the Members table and update the regions value based on the mailing_state prescence in the new arrays.

I'm struggling with writing a working sql statement to do this. I figured since this is a one time update, I could just run it directly from the database.

Comment: Which DB is used?

Comment: Please show the data structure so we could recommend an SQL query.

Comment: @Rohit I'm using PHPmyAdmin

Comment: @IldarAkhmetov If i'm understanding you correctly.

Members table:
user_id   mailing_state   region

Comment: @IldarAkhmetov Sorry thjat didn't post correctly.
http://oi66.tinypic.com/241nggo.jpg

The mailing_city isn't relevant, but I just included it. I can't really show anymore of the data besides those. But it does have first name, last name, user_id

Comment: @wcsdarren the link shows nothing :)